# Lightbox Plugins Not Working

Tags: jquery, plugins, wordpress, lightbox

I had a responsive lightbox plugin installed on our site and it's recently stopped working, I've tried installing other plugins but it seems no lightbox plugin will work. Does anyone know what could be causing this problem? We currently have dFactory's "Responsive Lightbox 1.6.8" installed.

I work for a non-profit and we can't afford to spend money on developers so I'd love all the help I can get. Please feel free to let me know if any other info is required.

These are image link examples:
http://www.smbgc.org/our-history/
http://www.smbgc.org/2016-youth-of-the-year/

Comment: could be anything, there is an js error as well so you would prob be best to get someone involved, but its prob down to a plugin/ theme issue

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the problem is too vague for me to troubleshoot. My suggestion is to test the plugin.

1. Turn off all the plugins except that one and use the default WP theme and see if that works.
2. If it works, then turn on one plugin at a time and test until you find one that doesn't work.
3. Or restore to the older version of the plugins (if you have a backup of the site, you can try that).

If none of these works, I can suggest you another plugin which works for me.  The Foo Gallery plugin and the FooBox Free Image Lightbox.

I used that on my site and i have no problem (running the latest WP version w/ a whole bunch of plugins).